# Most efficient way to Array.Resize with something other than "0" as default value?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory-management, floating-point, resize

I'd like to resize an array, however I don't want all the appended values to be zero.

```
Array.Resize(ref range, range.Length + grow);
```

If you assume that the appended length is always a multiple of 4 bytes (just enough to hold a float), what is the best way to fill this up with either `float.MaxValue` or `float.MinValue`?

Comment: A loop is the correct way to do this. You could always start mucking about with fixed memory access to the underlying bytes, but do you really need to?

Comment: Do you know what functions I would use within that loop? Just a pointer may be enough to get me started..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop through the added items and assign the value to it. The compiler will produce code to only do the range checking of the array indexes once outside the loop, so the loop will be very efficient.

```
int oldSize = range.Length;
Array.Resize(ref range, range.Length + grow);
for (int i = oldSize; i < range.Length; i++) {
  range[i] = float.MinValue;
}
```

You should be aware that the `Array.Resize` doesn't actually resize the array, but it creates a new array with the desired size and copies the data from the original array. So, if you want a way to resize a collection efficiently, you shouldn't use an array at all. Depending on your needs something like a List, a List of arrays, or a LinkedList would probably be better.

Comment: Lists use arrays as backing stores. There is array copying in lists under certain conditions as they are resized.